# How to not create a list every time the activity is created

Tags: java, android, list

My code does this - `List<HashMap<String, String>> painItems = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();` every time the activity is created, but I want it to persist the list throughout the application life cycle, and even when the application is closed then re-opened... Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Why all the hate?  I get what the OP is asking for easily enough...  If it's a dup, mark it as such.  Otherwise, it's a reasonable question.

Comment: thanks. do you have any idea how to solve my problem?

Comment: sadly, no.  (*especially* since it appears to now be the most popular tag on SO. ;)  )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answer here?

[Activity Result Fix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6714456/add-item-to-listview-after-passing-info-through-an-intent-android/6714690#6714690)

UPDATE:

After that you will need to cache the information on the device and set it to refresh. in onClose() serialize the painItems ArrayList to a file using FileOutputStream fed by ObjectOutputStream to write your list out to a file.  Use ObjectInputStream from a FileInputStream to read it back in. I recommend doing this in onPostResume() and notify the empty initialized adapter of the data set change.

UPDATE 2:

The shamelessly terse Exception handling below needs to be thought out but this should get you started.

```
String serfilename = "painitems.ser";

...

private ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> loadListFromFile(
    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> masterlistrev) {
try {
    FileInputStream fis = openFileInput(serfilename);
    ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(fis);
    masterlistrev = (ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>) ois.readObject();
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
return masterlistrev;
}

private void writeListToFile(ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> masterlistrev){
    File myfile = getFileStreamPath(serfilename);
try {
    if(myfile.exists() || myfile.createNewFile()){
        FileOutputStream fos = openFileOutput(serfilename, MODE_PRIVATE);
        ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(fos);
        oos.writeObject(masterlistrev);
    }
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}

}
```

Comment: mbarnes, i implemented the startActivityForResult, but the list still goes away after closing the application and starts a new list. I didn't have time to test your sample code(i just changed stuff in my own code), but is there something you added in order to save this list?

Comment: You will need to cache the information on the device and set it to refresh onPostResume();

Comment: if you have time, it would be of great help if you could give me some idea using code on how to do this... or if not, some tutorial that uses this method. otherwise, thank you very much.

Comment: are you sure you are talking about onClose()? I don't quite see this in the Android Reference...unless you are talking about onDestroy() or onStop()?

Comment: onStop()... and now that I have tried it... I think onCreate is better for this application. You are likely going to do some thinking about this one. But here come the basics.

Comment: thank you! it gives a null pointer exception at: ` File myfile = getFileStreamPath(serfilename);` By the way, I just initialized serfilename as a String, simply using `String serfilename;` before onCreate(). In the OnCreate() method, after super.onCreate(), I put `if(loadListFromFile((ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>) painItems) != null)
  painItems = loadListFromFile((ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>) painItems);` I had to typecaste it and use that if statement. I also put an OnStop() method, in which I did `super.onStop(), `writeListToFile((ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>) painItems)`

Comment: i am not sure how to solve the nullpointerexception... is serfilename supposed to be set to something?

Comment: String serfilename = "painitems.ser" needs to be added as a field. I think I fill mine in at onCreate().

Comment: i know it has been a long time, but I am once again encountering a similar problem. When I reboot the phone, the device does not recover the saved list. I think that this is OnDestroy()...what is the solution to this?

Comment: Couple of questions that might help narrow it down: What path are you saving to? If you are using getCacheDir() the files are not persistent for instance. Have you tried creating an activity that does nothing more than serialize a strawman Map and restore it? Reducing the issue down to the code may make the problem obvious, and then also make it easier to diagnose.  If reducing doesn't produce an obvious result please post the code.

Comment: mbarnes, could you please take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6849568/specific-onitemclick-intent-android/6849790#6849790? Sorry to not keep you updated, but I think the saving is working as of now. If you could help me solve my other question it would be highly appreciated. The answers as of now are not working too well for me.

Comment: onPause() is the only Activity method that is guaranteed to be run when the system orders a shutdown. onStop() and onDestroy() may never be run.  This link may provide you some insight: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals/activities.html#Lifecycle

Answer (score 2):

You are going to need to save it somewhere, SQLite DB, TextFile, XML etc. Take a look at the android activity life-cycle http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html and decide where you want to save and where you want to load your list.

To clarify you will need to pull the values out of your  HashMap and store them in a text format using one of the methods mentioned above. Then when your app starts you have to get the values from storage and load them into the HashMap.

Answer (score 0):

When the activity is closed you will probably be out of luck, if it was destroyed, but, otherwise make it part of the class level properties, and check if it exists before creating it again, but doing it in the `onCreate` method is probably your best bet, since that is only called once/activity.

Now, if you have data there and you want that created only one time then you may want to look at something like `SharedPreferences` (http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html) so you can create the list, then just pull it in and display it from then on.

I did this, which is related to what you are asking.  The nice part of `final` is that you only set it once, which is what you want. (http://www.javamex.com/tutorials/synchronization_final.shtml)

```
public class StartGameActivity extends GraphicsActivity implements
    final List<PaintColorCanvas> pccList = new ArrayList<PaintColorCanvas>();
```